# how can I decrease the number of variables?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, logic

```
public class Mavenproject8
 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     int num=100+(int)(Math.random()*900);
   Scanner blue=new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("enter 3 numbers from 1 to 9:");
   int n1=blue.nextInt();
   int n2=blue.nextInt();
   int n3=blue.nextInt();
   int c3=num%10;
   num/=10;
   int c2=num%10;
   int c1=num/10;
   int max=9;
   while(max!=0){
       if(n1==c1&&n2==c2&&n3==c3){max=0;System.out.println("Congratulations, You Won !!!");}
       else{System.out.println("you can try for "+max+" times\nenter 3 digits");
       n1=blue.nextInt();
       n2=blue.nextInt();      
       n3=blue.nextInt();max--;}
   }
 if(max==0){System.out.println("You can try for 0 times");}
 } 
}
```

//i think the code could be smaller and could done with better logic
//how can i decrease the number of integers or maybe shrink the code with a better logic

Comment: You can always use arrays.

Comment: Use an array for both the _n_ and _c_ values.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mavenproject8 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 100 + (int) (Math.random() * 900);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter 3 numbers from 1 to 9:");
    int max = 9;

    while (max-- > 0) {
        System.out.printf("You can try for %d times%nEnter 3 digits:%n", max + 1);

        int[] userDigits = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            userDigits[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        int[] numDigits = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            numDigits[i] = num % 10;
            num /= 10;
        }

        if (Arrays.equals(userDigits, numDigits)) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations, You Won !!!");
            return;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("You can try for 0 times");
}}
```

Changes are:

1. Replaced individual variables n1, n2, n3, c1, c2, c3 with arrays userDigits and numDigits.
2. Used loops to read user input and extract digits from num.
3. Utilized Arrays.equals() to compare arrays for equality.

Hope that helps...